# Databricks Autoloader SchemaHints

Tags: databricks, databricks-autoloader

I am using a Autoloader to load CSV data from a S3 bucket and I am executing the autoloader query using a DLT. My DLT works fine and it creates the table based on the query but when it creates the table all the fields seems to be of 'string' datatype.

```
CREATE OR REFRESH STREAMING LIVE TABLE S3_TABLE
AS SELECT * FROM cloud_files('s3://path/to/s3/', 'csv',map("delimiter", ",","schemaHints","COB DATE,BALANCE FLOAT"));
```

By my query I am trying to change the type for these two fields(COB & BALANCE) but the table is created with string as datatype. Am I missing something here?